# Custom textposition not function when barmode is stack in bar chart plotly

Tags: python, plotly

The custom `textposition` is not function when `barmode= stack` in bar chart.

Previously, using `barmode= group`, `textposition` able to function. But the chart looking samller compare to `barmode= stack`.

Code:

```
fig = px.bar(pie_bar_gp, x='columnx', y='columny', title='' ,orientation='h' 
                ,text='columnx', text_auto=",.2f"
                ,color = 'columny'
                ,color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Brwnyl
                )      

fig.update_layout(barmode="stack", showlegend=False)

txt_position = ['outside' if x <= 2000000 else 'inside' for x in pie_bar_gp['columnx']]
fig.update_traces(textposition=txt_position, textangle=0)
```

Anyone can assist?

Comment: Please add small data to your question. Or print the following `pie_bar_gp.head(10).to_dict()` and add it to the question.

Comment: I have experimented a lot, but it seems that text positions are only valid for single settings and not for individual position settings. Try setting the `text_ position='outside'`. Only the last label is external due to the stacked graph functionality.